# Drag and drop text with mouse

Tags: mouse, text, web-browser

Something I often find myself doing is drag and dropping text one website into another app (e.g. Notes). Using the trackpad, the process works as I expect it to.

However, when I use my external mouse (regular mouse, a Logitech G403), I have to do this:

1. Select the text I want to drag
2. Click and hold the left mouse button for about a second over the selected area
3. Start dragging

Skipping step 2 will simply cause the OS to ignore my old selection and start a new one.

How can I disable this behavior so I can immediately start dragging a selected text area?

Tested in Safari and Edge browsers, Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: How would the os know when your done dragging and to “drop” the text?  How would it differentiate between one set of text snd selecting another?  Does the existing copy/paste not fill your need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable text drag delay](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166383/how-to-disable-text-drag-delay) Comments say it stopped working at High Sierra; Tinkertool *might* still be able to do it, but it probably only adjusts the same defaults as Terminal. [Having said that, I shortened mine to 100ms years ago & it still works in Mojave].